# Is it possible to determine the location of a context menu in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, flash

I am trying to find the best way to improve the user experience when interacting with a context menu in a Flex application.  I already know that the context menu in Flex is quite limited in terms of how it is constructed and what it can show.

What I was hoping to do was to implement something similar to what Microsoft Word does in 2010 or later, where when right clicking a little floating palette is displayed above the common popup menu.  I was hoping that there was a way to 1) listen for an event that is triggered when a context menu is displayed, and 2) determine the location of the context menu so that I could display a floating palette above the context menu as in Word.  So far, I have not found out how to accomplish either of these things.

I suspect that there might be some focus and stage management issues with this approach generally, but I was hoping to at least get to the point where those issues were discovered.  Any ideas?

And for the record, I am familiar with the JavaScript hack to override the default context menu in a Flex app.  May have to go there eventually, but hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, native context menu in Flash doesn't allow to place any custom graphics above it. And the second problem is it blocks user interaction with Flash movie during appearance. So I think you haven't any chances to deal with it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the response.